# pointer inside a structure pointer not returned after malloc

Tags: pointers, malloc, structure

I'm scratching my head over this since quite long.

```
typedef struct B_{
   /* something */
}B;

typedef struct A_{
   B* pointB;
}A;

func1(A *pointA)
{
   pointA->pointB = malloc(SOMESIZE);
}

function(A *pointA)
{
   /* STATE 1 
    * pointA is perfectly allocated here and 
    * pointB inside pointA is NULL at this moment.
    */

   func1(pointA);

   /* STATE 2
    * pointB is still NULL at this moment??
    */
}
```

In `function()`, the argument `pointA` is perfectly allocated structure with several members and a pointer `pointB` which is `NULL`. I'm calling another function which takes `pointA` as argument and allocates `pointB`. I debugged and I can see `pointB` getting an address after `malloc`, but when I return from `func1()` I still see `pointB` as `NULL`. I think this looks like I'm passing `pointA` as value and not by reference, but I'm having a really hard time getting this into my head. I'm passing a perfectly valid structure pointer whose member pointer is NULL and I'm allocating that member pointer.

Comment: This should work just fine. So something else is going on, i.e.. you're doing something wrong somewhere. Try post the real code, an example which can be compiled and run.

Comment: I know, this is part of the legacy code and shouldn't have this issue. We made some other changes unrelated to this, but part of the change is accessing `pointB` after `func1()` call. Since `pointB` is NULL, we caught a NULL pointer exception.

Comment: Well, then anyone reading this has orders of magnitude less info about what's going on in the actual code than what you have - so it's hard to point out where the bug is. The only suggestion really is to run your program under a memory debugger such as valgrind and see if it catches any buffer overflows or similar errors.

Comment: What is SOMESIZE?  Is it based on a variable or is it a fixed size.  On some architectures malloc(0) returns 0, on others they return something legal.

Comment: @cup: SOMESIZE is sizeof(struct B_) actually, it's not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following program, let me know if yours is similar to this:

```
typedef struct B_{
    /* something */   
}B;

typedef struct A_{
    B* pointB; 
}A;

func1(A *pointA)
{
    pointA->pointB = malloc(SOMESIZE);
    printf("\nValue of pointB:%p\n", (void*)(pointA->pointB));
}

function(A *pointA)  // Check in Debugger, For me this is coming as NULL
{
    /* STATE 1 
     * pointA is perfectly allocated here and 
     * pointB inside pointA is NULL at this moment.
    */

    pointA = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A)); 
    if (pointA == NULL) {
       printf("\nReturning NULL from malloc\n");
       exit(0);
    } 
    printf("\nValue of pointA:%p\n", (void*)pointA);
    func1(pointA);
    printf("\nValue of pointB:%p\n", (void*)(pointA->pointB));

    /* STATE 2
     * pointB is still NULL at this moment??
    */
}

int main() 
{
     A *pointA = NULL;

     // Passing pointA as value from here, so it will be NULL after this call.
     function1(pointA);

     return 0;
}
```

Here, pointA is passed as value to function1() , thus after returning from this function, it will still be NULL. So, i think there is some issue with debugger.

Value of pointA:0xa39010

Value of pointB:0xa39030

Value of pointB:0xa39030

Comment: Yes, the scenario is exactly the same. I tried it too on a linux machine and got the same results. I honestly would have noticed it in the production code if there was some external factor to this, but there isn't. We're just passing a structure pointer and allocating a memory for the member pointer. Memory gets allocated to the member pointer but after returning from func1(), pointB is zero. I've given up coz I honestly have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: But why are you passing (A*) to your parent function(). Let us suppose, debugger is giving wrong results and actually pointB gets allocated, but what is the point. When you return from function(), you loose both. Is my understanding correct here.

Comment: Infact, when I passed pointer to pointA to function(), things are working fine and debugger is printing proper values.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, `pointA` is an allocated structure pointer having some other populated members as well, including `pointB=0x0`. Now purpose of `func1()` is to allocate resources for `pointA`, which included allocating memory for `pointB`. So we call `func1(pointA)` expecting `pointB` to be allocated and we access `pointB->memberB`, causing NPE. Debugger is showing `pointB` to be allocated while I'm inside `func1()`, and to be NULL when I step out.

Comment: would it be possible for you to paste the exact piece of code which is having trouble. Dont see a problem otherwise with this code.

Comment: I'm really sorry I can't do that for obvious reasons. This is as exact and simplified as I make it. I was hoping it to be a basic pointer issue but it looks something different. On Monday I'll be able to consult some colleagues and find out the issue. Thanks a lot for your help though.